# How can I get the length of a list in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I tried to do the following:

```
quizes = Quiz.query.all()
math_quizzes = [quiz for quiz in quizes if quiz.category == "Math" and len(math_quizzes) < 10]
```

But `len(math_quizzes) < 10` doesn't work, So how can I do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Do you want the list comprehension to return a tuple of two values? One being a list and another being the length of list? Also what are you expecting > len(math_quizzes) < 10 to do? That's a comparison between ints.

Comment: No, I am trying to get the quizzes that are of the category: Math, And only the first 10 by len(math_quizzes) < 10

Comment: `math_quizzes` doesn't exist until __after__ the comprehension is finished. Your best bet is to add a `[:10]` after the comprehension to get only the first 10 elements from it.

Comment: Well you're trying to get the length of a variable that hasn't finished being declared.

Comment: @rdas You mean I should use: math_quizzes[:10] ?

Comment: Yes, @rdas's solution is perfect

Comment: `[quiz for quiz in quizes if quiz.category == "Math"][:10]`. The comprehension creates a list. Then you pick the first 10 elements from it to create `math_quizzes`

Comment: On a slightly off topic note, I believe list comprehension a are not for such cases (personal opinion). I always use them when I have to do something on entire range and get all results. @crayxt's solution is what you should be looking at

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try to limit it on `Query` side?

```
math_quizzes = Quiz.query.filter(Quiz.category == "math").limit(10).all()
```

Comment: Nice and pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Your `and` operation will not work, as you are trying it on same list `math_quizzes`, Try sliceing to print the number of records.

```
quizes = Quiz.query.all()
print([quiz for quiz in quizes if quiz.category == "Math"][:11])
```